# how to solve this error when I was configure /etc/shadowsocks.conf

Tags: python

[image: when i try to configure the shadowsocks on my server,i encountered an error below.can anyone help me out ? thx]
i have read the tutorial below ,but still can not solve this problem.
https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks/wiki/Configuration-via-Config-File

Comment: There is absolutely no good reason to post a screenshot. That is text, please post it as text.

Answer (score 1):

The program can't bind the socket. This might happen when the IP / port combination is in use already or if there are OS limitation, like firewall restrictions or using a port below 1024 as normal user.